# Ungroup items in taskbar (launcher) in Unity

Tags: unity, launcher

As you can see in the image below, there are 3 instances of Firefox and file manager is open and all of them are grouped together. But I do not want them to be grouped. I looked into unity tweak tool and Ubuntu system settings but I could not find how to ungroup this.

Is there any way I can do this? I am using Unity 7.5 and Ubuntu 17.

[image]